# why do we need to specify 1 in the command iptables -I INPUT 1

Tags: linux, iptables

While I configure the Linux firewall there is  a command

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

In this command why do we need to specify `1` after `INPUT`

Comment: What happens if you omit it? Show the complete in- and output.

Answer (score 2):

We don't:

> IPTABLES(8)
>   iptables 1.4.19.1
>
> NAME
>          iptables — administration tool for IPv4 packet filtering and NAT
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          ...
>
> ```
>    iptables [-t table] -I chain [rulenum] rule-specification
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to:

```
vm ~ # iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
vm ~ # iptables -L -vn
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 2250 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
vm ~ #
```